# Perl system call throws strange error

Tags: perl, shell, system

I just wrote a perl script that is restarting a list of services on a linux server. It's intended to run as a cron job. when I execute the script though, I keep getting this error;

```
root@www:~/scripts# ./ws_restart.pl
  * Stopping web server apache2                                   [ OK ]
sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
  * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                         [ OK ]
sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

The call that is being used to do this is;

```
system("/etc/init.d/apache2 stop");
system("/etc/init.d/mysql stop");
```

I can paste the entire script code if needed, but I figured that this is the source of the problem and just need to know how to stop it.

Any ideas?

Here's the entire script;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $old_pids = {};
my $post_stop_ids = {};
my @services = qw/apache2 mysql solr/;
my $app_dir  = '/home/grip/apps/eventfinder';


# collect existing pids then kill services
foreach my $service (@services) {
  # gather up existing pids
  $old_pids->{$service} = [ get_pids_by_process($service) ];

  # issue stop command to each service
  set_service_state($service, 'stop');

  # attempt to regather same ids
  $post_stop_ids->{$service} = [ get_pids_by_process($service) ];

  # kill any rogue ids left over
  kill_rogue_procs($post_stop_ids->{$service});

  # give each kill time to finish
  sleep(5);
}


# attempt to restart killed services
foreach my $service (@services) {
  # issue start command to each service
  set_service_state($service, 'start');

  # Let's give each service enough time to crawl outta bed.
  # I know how much I hate waking up
  sleep(5);
}

# wait for it!...wait for it! :P
# Pad an extra 5 seconds to give solr enough time to come up before we reindex
sleep(5);

# start the reindexing process of solr
system("cd $app_dir ; RAILS_ENV=production rake reindex_active");

# call it a day...phew!
exit 0;

sub kill_rogue_procs {
  my @ids = shift;
  # check if we still have any rogue processes that failed to die
  # if so, kill them now.
  if(scalar @ids) {
    foreach my $pid (@ids) {
      system("kill $pid");
    }
  }
}


sub set_service_state {
  my ($proc, $state) = @_;

  if($proc eq 'apache2') {
    system("/etc/init.d/apache2 $state");
  } elsif($proc eq 'mysql') {
    system("/etc/init.d/mysql $state");
  } elsif($proc eq 'solr') {
    system("cd $app_dir ; RAILS_ENV=production rake sunspot:solr:$state");
  }
}


sub get_pids_by_process {
  my $proc = shift;

  my @proc_ids = ();

  open(PSAE, "/bin/ps -ae | grep $proc |") || die("Couldn't run command");

  while(<PSAE>) {
    push @proc_ids, $_ =~ /(\d{1,5})/;
  }

  close PSAE;

  return @proc_ids;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try `perl -e 'system("/etc/init.d/apache2 stop");'`?

Comment: Works fine that way. I'll paste the code.

Comment: Do you know what $state is at that point?

Comment: Actually, I'd be more suspicious of what's in @ids in kill_rogue_procs.

Comment: Well, I would imagine that $state would be the value passed in during that iteration through the array. Let me run this in debug and see what it is really quick.

Comment: I was just thinking about the rogue sub also. I'm wondering if the $pid val isn't somehow wrong. Going to check that in debugger also.

Comment: Yeah, it is the rogue sub. The @ids array had values, but when it tried to execute the kill command is when it threw the error. I'll try a kill at the command line to see what that does. I think I will be able to dig out the issue from this now. Thanks for you assistance, Paul.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I'd be more suspicious of what's in @ids in kill_rogue_procs.  It's the result of a ps followed by a grep, so might have bogus values if ps doesn't return any results or if the pid isn't 5 digits long.

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
sub kill_rogue_procs {
  my @ids = shift;
  # check if we still have any rogue processes that failed to die
  # if so, kill them now.
  if(scalar @ids) {
```

From what you're passing to this sub, @ids will always contain a single array reference, so (scalar @ids) will always be true. It also means you end up passing something like the following to `sh`:

```
kill ARRAY(0x91b0768)
```

You want something like (if the arrayref is empty, there's nothing to loop over anyway):

```
my $ids = shift;
...
for my $pid (@$ids) {
  kill SIGTERM => $pid;
```

Or instead of the loop:

```
kill SIGTERM => @$ids;
```

Also, there is no need to call system to [kill](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html) a process.

To this, I'd add the last line, so you don't grep the grep process itself:

```
sub get_pids_by_process {
  my $proc = shift;
  $proc =~ s/^(.)/[$1]/;
```

Comment: This is all excellent advice. I haven't tried them yet, but will most definitely add them in. The one thing I like about perl is how the more seasoned you get in the language, the less you have to do to achieve the same results. I'm not a perl guru, but I'm sure you can gauge my level of expertise from my script. Thanks very much for sharing this, runrig.

Comment: @runrig, You were just one step away from the answer, so I added it in.

Answer (score 1):

As `sh` is raising the errors, I'm pretty sure one of the parameters to `system` is being expanded to something unexpected. I'd print all parameters just prior to passing them to system for a quick debug.

Comment: I tried altering the system call to call the kill command as /bin/kill, but that still didn't stop it. I did notice though that if it tries to kill a non-existent pid that you get this sh message: "bash: kill: (31014) - No such process". That might be where it's getting that opening paren from perhaps?

Comment: @Skittles, "altering the system call" wasn't the advice given. The advice given was very good and you should follow it.